# LINQ to SQL

Tags: linq-to-sql

While trying to use LINQ to SQL I encountered several problems.

**I have table persons:**

- int ID
- string firstName
- string lastName

**And table notes that has:**

- int ID
- string noteText
- string createdBy
- datetime creationDate
- int PersonID

PersonID is a foreign key and the relationship is 1:n

I tried to use LINQ to SQL to create a person and some notes for each person.

```
Person person =  new person();
Person.firstName = "me";
Person.note = new note();   
Person.note.noteText = "some text…"; 

_DataContext.Persons.InsertOnSubmit(person);   
_DataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

The problem is that the person object doesn't yet exist in the DB so it doesn't have an ID yet. So the note.personID filed has a 0 value… (the ID field is an identity field in the sql server)

The only solution for this that I found is to create a person , submitchanges and then create a note and submitchanges again.

Am I missing something here or maybe that’s the way one should work with LINQ to SQL?

How can I add multiple notes per person with LTS? I have a 1:n relationship and I don't see it with LTS.

If a person has 10000 notes, I don't want the person object constructor to load all the notes he has. I want to load them only when I refer to them. How can I config LTS to load the notes on demand?

Comment: is your PersonID a foreign key on notes table? If so it should be automatically managed the way you want

Comment: Very well-written question! +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you aren't using the LinqToSql class designer, you should think about using it.  The classes it generates will support the insertion scenario you outlined.

I can tell you aren't using the designer because it would give you a Notes (plural) property on the Person... as Person is 1 to Many with Notes.

> How can I config LTS to load the notes on demand?

The designer will generate a property of type EntitySet(Note), which will load Notes on demand.

Comment: Well actually I am using the designer, I just added my tables with the relations from the DB and it doesn't work like you described.
maybe I should configure something to change the way it works?
I configured the relationship to be 1 to many and still no notes collection or something...

Comment: Hmm.  Ok.  Here's Scott Guthrie's blog about the designer.  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx   He's showing the insert scenario you describe.  Check the properties of the relationship to make sure that it's Person.Id to Note.PersonId

Comment: Yep found the problem, the relationship wasn't configured correctly at the SQL server. now everything is working just great.
Thanks allot.
Omri.